# How to remove a class

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, actions

Is it possible to remove classes from a plugin and add theme into to theme?

I need to modify Woocommerce `WP_Checkout` class but I want to move it to my theme folder so if woocommerce will be updated my changes will not be effected. Is theme some way to make an remove and add action/hook? Or maybe unhook page and add my custom page with the class?

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Comment: You cannot actually remove a class but you can override it. I think [this tutorial](http://chrislema.com/improving-the-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button/) may get you up and running.

Comment: There are a ton of hooks/filters depending on what *specfically* you are trying to change in the `WC_Checkout` class.  You could also try extending the class.

Answer (score 1):

The class `WC_Checkout` is assigned to a member of the class `Woocommerce`. So maybe something like this could work:

```
add_action( "plugins_loaded", "wpse_91273_custom_checkout", 999 );

function wpse_91273_custom_checkout()
{
    $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->checkout = new Custom_Checkout;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I tried to put above code in functions.php also included my new class and included `exit;` in new function. But the process still works. How can I see if it's replaced?

Comment: Add `die( __CLASS__ );` to one of the called methods.